# How do I generate synthetic data w/ Faker for a data model and ensure referential integrity

Tags: python, sql, database, data-modeling, faker

I am currently building a data model and would like to populate this model with synthetic data. [Faker](https://faker.readthedocs.io/en/master/) seems to be the most optimal Python package I could use, although if anyone else has any alternatives please suggest below.

I've not figured out how I can ensure that the data I genereate adhere's to the relationships I model in my data model, and after a bit looking at the docs I'm not sure I can do this. Does anyone know how I could do this using Faker (preferably, although other ideas/tools are welcome).